# How do I use opposite sign in where condition in dataProvider?

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I'm beginner in Yii2. I want to use opposite sign in where clause in dataProvider.

like blow code.

```
where(['sent' => '!= guest'])
```

what can I use instead of `!=`?

Comment: where(['NOT IN','sent','guest'])

Comment: Thanks a lot. it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use as below.

```
where(['not in','sent',$array])
```